# API query doesn't work, always get me empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My problem is API issue, i want to get the product Id (`pid`) from query then i can get data related of that product from database (like `month` and `sales`). Below at the end is my API code for you to correct me or appoint the where the miss, but before that, let me show you my tests with postman and its results:

1. Let's test API without query, it will get all orders that i made from DB:

`[Get] localhost:5000/api/orders/income` =>

```
[
  {
    "_id": 8,        //product Id = 62e531d9f4a228d96c211ee9    *
    "total": 100
  },
  {
    "_id": 9,        //product Id = 62e531d9f4a228d96c211ee9    *
    "total": 700
  },
  {
    "_id": 7,        //product Id = 62e7ef02d37eda799894e61d
    "total": 400
  },
  {
    "_id": 10,       //productId = 62e531d9f4a228d96c211ee9     *
    "total": 990
  },
  {
    "_id": 11,       //productId = 62cc4eb56d10ae0a3c0af363
    "total": 20
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,        //productId = 62cc4eb56d10ae0a3c0af363
    "total": 224
  }
]
```

2. Ok now let's test this API with query and shoose id of product that repeated 3 times `?pid=62e531d9f4a228d96c211ee9`:

`[Get] localhost:5000/api/orders/income?pid=62e531d9f4a228d96c211ee9` =>

```
[]      //yes, it gives me an empty array (undefinded), this is my problem.
```

API code :

```
router.get("/income", verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {
    const productId = req.query.pid;
    console.log(req.query.pid);        //62e531d9f4a228d96c211ee9
    const date = new Date();
    const lastMonth = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1));
    const previousMonth = new Date(new Date().setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 1));
    console.log(previousMonth);       //2022-06-02T10:54:30.937Z

    try {
        const income = await Order.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    createdAt: { $gte: previousMonth },
                    ...(productId && {
                        products: { $elemMatch: { productId } }
                    }),
                },
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    month: { $month: "$createdAt" },
                    sales: "$amount",
                },
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$month",
                    total: { $sum: "$sales" },
                },
            },
        ]);
        res.status(200).json(income);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```

order Model code:

```
{
        userId: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        products: [
            {
                productId: {
                    trype: String,
                },
                quantity: {
                    type: Number,
                    default: 1,
                },
            }
        ],
        amount: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        address: {
    //...
},
{ timestamps: true }
```

Comment: Since you are querying with a single property of the array field, you don't need to use the `$elemMatch` in the `$match` stage filter - this will do: `{ "products.productId": req.query.pid, createdAt: ... }`.

Comment: @prasad_ i half understand your comment but i can't fully get how to transform my code into it

Comment: Your match stage filter can be just this: `{ "products.productId": req.query.pid, createdAt: { $gte: previousMonth } }`.

Comment: `$match: {
                    "products.productId": req.query.pid, createdAt: { $gte: previousMonth }
                },` didn't work

Comment: keeps getting me empty array `[]`

Comment: You need to make sure the `req.query.pid` and `previousMonth` have the correct data.

Comment: `clg req.query.pid` gets me `62e531d9f4a228d96c211ee9` id of product that i'm looking for its data, and `clg (previousMonth )` gives me the whole date `2022-06-02T10:41:10.125Z`